# Create multiple "Values" from ModelBuilder Iterator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am using "Iterate Row Selection" in ModelBuilder to run through every line of a table. I am able to have the iterator create a rolling variable (Value), by selecting a field in "Group by Fields."

If I "Group by Fields" on the field `CNTRY_NAME`, the iterator creates a value for that record on each iteration (i.e. Afghanistan). I can then plug the variable into a different part of the model as an input.

I would like it to create a **second** value for an additional field (i.e.  `CNTRY_ID`) on each iteration, based on the current selected record. By default, the iterator only creates one value.

If I add an additional field into the Group By Fields, the fields are concatenated, and I still only get one "Value" variable.

[image: ModelBuilder]
[image]

**Is there a way to create an additional "Value" variable from an iterator in ModelBuilder?**

Comment: Can you amend your question to explain what you mean by an "additional" value. What is this additional value and where would it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using the model only tool [Get Field Value](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/get-field-value.htm) as shown below:

[image: Using Get Field tool]

This logic works as your iterator is creating a virtual table of just one row per country. So you can use this tool to pull out any other field value in your "one row table". In the example above you can then use %country ID% in any inline substitution.

Comment: THANK YOU! The "Get Field Value" tool doesn't appear in a basic search. That toolset is hidden within the ModelBuilder window under "Insert."

Comment: I don't think any of the model only tools appear in the search panel, just something you learn about after banging your head against a very hard brick wall! :)